# Better way to parse the env variable?

Tags: rust, dotenv

I'm just new to the rust and I'M trying to make a env parsing for my project and i'm unable to find a proper way to parse the env files. i use the `dotenv` crate. is there any better way for the error handling and proper env loading?

```
// loads the .env file located in enviroments current directory or its parents in sequence
use dotenv;

pub struct Configs{
    pub username: String,
    pub password: String,
}


pub fn load_configs() -> Configs {
    dotenv::dotenv().ok();

    Configs{
        username: match dotenv::var("USERNAME"){
            Ok(username) => username,
            Err(error) => {
                println!("{error}");
                String::from("not found")
            }
        },
        password: match dotenv::var("PASSWORD"){
            Ok(password) => password,
            Err(error) => {
                println!("{error}");
                String::from("not found")
            }
        },
    }
}    

impl Configs{
    pub fn show_variables(&self){
        println!("{}\n{}",self.username,self.password);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem with the code you have?

Comment: Please read the [chapter about error handling](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch09-00-error-handling.html) in the Rust book. What you should use here is a return type of `Result<Configs, dotenv::Error>`, and the [`?` operator](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch09-02-recoverable-errors-with-result.html#a-shortcut-for-propagating-errors-the--operator) to return errors.

Comment: If the environment variables should have a default value, use [`unwrap_or_else`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.unwrap_or_else).

Comment: "Better way to parse the env variable?" sounds like you want a [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2):

There's this crate https://crates.io/crates/envy.  Also, provided the information in this README is correct, there's a security advisory for the dotenv crate.  This guy is an alternative: https://crates.io/crates/dotenvy

Also, if it were up to me I'd use `dotenvy::dotenv()` somewhere higher up the call chain (probs `main`) and load `Config` directly from the environment.  In my experience having the option to remove/isolate dotenv loading from config loading down the line is pretty handy.

ex:

```rust
use dotenvy::dotenv_iter;
use serde::Deserialize;

#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct Config {
    #[serde(default = "default_username")]
    username: String,
    #[serde(default = "default_password")]
    password: String,
}

impl Config {
    pub fn from_dotenv() -> Self {
        envy::from_iter::<Self>(dotenv_iter().unwrap()).expect("Failed to load env")
    }
}

fn default_username() -> String {
    "not found".to_string()
}

fn default_password() -> String {
    "not found".to_string()
}
```